# how to print sql query of view in runtime

Tags: views

I would like to see **view's sql query that is executed in runtime**. I found this method in google, `hook_views_pre_execute`, but I am really beginner in drupal. Where I have to apply this method, when I put this method as `project_views_pre_execute` in `template.php`, nothing is shown and I don't know why, is it needed to write it in custom module?

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: try [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module.

Comment: Could you explain me detail, pls.

Comment: You could use this module to view the queries log for the page being loaded with their execution time.

Answer (score 0):

The [Devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) provides a SQL query log for debugging/performance testing. You can enable this under **Configuration > Development > Devel settings** (/admin/config/development/devel) and by setting **Display query log** option.

[image]

Once enabled, the bottom of the page will contain all SQL queries executed in page rendering. For your needs, you'll need to look for `views_plugin_query_default::execute` function calls (the **where** column) to see the SQL query executed for your view.

[image]